# Accepting a bearer token from another REST API

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, web-services, bearer-token

I have a rest API (Parent) where a user requests a bearer token with username/password. This API can make a call to another API (Child) but I'd like the Parent's bearer token to server as authorization for Child access. I guess similar to how SSO works but for web services. How can this be done in .net core?

Comment: How your API make call to another API ? Any sample code or tried part will be help to resolve your issue.

Comment: [Does this article useful to you?](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/use-bearer-tokens-in-client-applications.html)

Comment: It will take some learning, but I think a separate IDP server is the correct solution for managing this. In the past I used IdentityServer4. My learning about this came from PluralSight so unfortunately I don't have a good free resource on hand